# Ubuntu 18.04 - DisplayLink not working (any more)

Tags: 18.04, displaylink

In Ubuntu 18.04 displaylink did not work.
I fixed it using a Ask-Ubuntu thread (unfortunately not sure which one)

After a long time I use Display Link again and it is not working any more.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Cause may be

- updated X in combination with Intel graphics card
- enabled secure boot

Try the following steps to fix it:

1. Disable secure boot
2. Try work-around from 
   [DisplayLink Ubuntu driver after recent X upgrades does not work with Intel GPUs](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades)